# Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute error?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
 public WorkflowQARuleSet GetQARule(int userNumber, int userNumberExternal, string applicationID,
         short computerNumber, long ruleBitID)
    {

        try
        {
            if (qaRules == null)
                qaRules = new List<WorkflowQARuleSet>();

            WorkflowQARuleSet wfQaRule = qaRules.FirstOrDefault(
                                                qaRule =>
                                                    qaRule != null &&
                                                    qaRule.QARuleBits63 != null &&
                                                    qaRule.QARuleBits63 == ruleBitID);

            if (wfQaRule == null)
            {
                WorkflowRuleSetApiClient workflowruleAPIClient = new WorkflowRuleSetApiClient(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["service:workflow_management_base_uri"]);

                wfQaRule = workflowruleAPIClient.GetQARuleSet(userNumber, userNumberExternal, applicationID, computerNumber, ruleBitID, WorkflowTypes.PaymentProcessing).FirstOrDefault();

            }




            if (wfQaRule != null)
                qaRules.Add(wfQaRule);

            if (wfQaRule != null && wfQaRule.QARuleBits63 == null)
                logger.Warn(string.Format("Invalid QA Rule Bits 63, {0}", wfQaRule.Name));

            return wfQaRule;


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error("Error in getting QA rule set.", ex);
            throw ex;
        }

    }
```

Here is my entire code and error

> System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
>      at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
>      at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNextRare()
>      at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
>      at Smi.Smart.PaymentProcessing.BusProcess.PaymentProcessingBP.GetQARule(Int32 userNumber, Int32 userNumberExternal, String applicationID, Int16 computerNumber, Int64 ruleBitID)

above is my code and error. can any one verify this?

Comment: This code does not throw that exception. Read [ask], post [mcve].

Comment: please see my entire code.

Comment: where can this error occure in my code?

Comment: I guess you're calling this method in a loop, then `qaRules.Add(wfQaRule)` is the cuplrit. Don't modify a collection you're iterating over. You would've found that if you put the exception message in your favorite web search engine.

Answer (score 3):

From your stack trace

> at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable1 source, Func2 predicate) at Smi.Smart.PaymentProcessing.BusProcess.PaymentProcessingBP.GetQARule(Int32...

you can see that the exception occurs during this enumeration of `quRules`:

```
WorkflowQARuleSet wfQaRule = qaRules.FirstOrDefault(
                                            qaRule =>
                                                qaRule != null &&
                                                qaRule.QARuleBits63 != null &&
                                                qaRule.QARuleBits63 == ruleBitID);
```

The only way I can think of how a `InvalidOperationException` can be thrown here is that you change the enumeration (`quRules`) in another thread while `FirstOrDefault` is enumerating.

So figure out which thread and which method change this set and do some synchronization. You could try a lock:

```
WorkflowQARuleSet wfQaRule; 
lock(qaRules)
    wfQaRule = qaRules.FirstOrDefault(
                                            qaRule =>
                                                qaRule != null &&
                                                qaRule.QARuleBits63 != null &&
                                                qaRule.QARuleBits63 == ruleBitID);
```

Note that you would need to `lock` the list in the other thread, too.

Comment: Thank you. for your solution ....:-)

Comment: What was the down vote for? Please comment on what's wrong with my answer, so I can do better next time. As far as I can see, I'm the only one who actually read the stack trace.

Comment: Sir i dont have reputations to vote you. thats whats the reason i didnt vote your answer

Comment: @NavyaSriGurram I did not mean you. Someone else voted this answer _down_.

Answer (score 1):

The GetQARuleSet or GetQARule method may have a loop, within the loop it is probably adding or removing members to the collection it is looping through.
Doing so will change the collection and end enumeration.

Modifying the collection from inside the loop, or from another thread are the main causes of this exception.

If you wish to add items to the collection you are looping through (or remove items)
You can store the items to add and items to remove in a temporary collection and then add or subtract them after the foreach() loop has finished.